# how to use facebook for user login on my website?

Tags: php, html, facebook

i am wondering how facebook works for logging in user on our websites.

I mean a user needs to be registered to my website for posting a comment, how can I check trough my php code if it's a logged user?

I heard you can only check if it's a logged user with javascript

Thanks for any explanation

Comment: For those of you who are looking to implement a Facebook login system in Javascript, here is an official Facebook tutorial: > *[Facebook Login Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) to check if a user is logged in with Facebook, and optionally get information about her/him. That way you can let your users complete their registrations or use your website with some restrictions.

But you need to register a Facebook Application first, as that application will be shown when asking the user about for permissions you require.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript to do this, but Facebook makes it pretty simple to use thier JavaScript lib. You **do** have access to whether or not the user is logged in in php using this method.

Take a look at the [single sign](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login) on section of the developers API.

Comment: Sorry but how i can check if a user is logged with php using javascript? I mean: i don't need javascript, i only need php check

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a software package like Wordpress or phpBB you could google around to find a plugin that did it for you. Otherwise, ignore this ;)