# Is sending unencrypted passwords a good pratice?

Tags: php, mysql, security, passwords

I'm building a website that will require registration and login.
Since I'm new to web developing, i was thinkink if sending unencrypted passwords to the server is an option.
Or, what you would reccomand me, since I don't know nothing about cryptography?

Edit: http://pastebin.com/nYcazcZq

Comment: Sending where using what? Can you show a specific example of what you are doing?

Comment: Here is the code i have written. How you can see the password is encrypted on the database, but not in the connectio between client and server. Have I to buy a SSL certificate, so? How and how much does it cost?

Comment: If the login has been already done, I do a check between the informations stored on the server and the session: does it really improve security?

Comment: You should use SSL on the login page to protect your users password. You should use ssl on the whole site to protect against session hijacking. Remember that if you have any users on an unencrypted wireless connection i a coffeshop or airport, then anyone can listen in on the traffic and read both usernames, passwords and session cookies unless you use ssl. Login without ssl does not make much sense. Try rapidssl.com.

Answer (score 2):

If your website is just for testing or for use within the intranet, it's not that big of a deal.

If not, **I highly suggest you use SSL.**

If you can't afford the certificate, at least give your users the option to :

- login with OpenID (as most OpenID providers offer SSL for authentification) ;
- login using Digest Authentication (which doesn't send the passwords in clear over the network).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean sending from browser to your server, then you need to use https/ssl to encrypt the connection, not the password itself. If on the other hand you're talking about storing passwords plaintext, then yes, that's bad as well. You should hash it with a strong salt (per user is best) and a slow algorithm.

This answer goes into more detail about sending passwords over SSL : [Sending passwords over the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797133/sending-passwords-over-the-web)

You can use PHP's crypt for hashing : http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that even when your service doesn't have any kind of valuable payload, it is guaranteed that many of your users will use the same password with it that they use with something more valuable, which means a breach or an easily-intercepted password on your end is capable of causing harm. Even if this is bad practice on the user's part, it's an unavoidable fact of life, so there is really no circumstance under which it is responsible to be blasé about user credentials with a publicly-accessible service. Please use SSL/https or OpenID (or another externally-hosted login management scheme, even Facebook: [how to use facebook for user login on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169491/how-to-use-facebook-for-user-login-on-my-website)) and if you are the password holder, please don't save them in the db as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

It is never good to send password unencrypted. For a serious web site you should encrypt the traffic between the browser and server using https. You do that by purchasing a certificate that you install on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

never send raw critical data on net,using ssl is best solution i  think,also you can use javascript encryptor to encrypt password in client side and decrypt in server,